# Bluetooth version on iMac

Tags: macos, bluetooth

How can I tell what Bluetooth version (i.e. 2.1 + EDR or 4.0) my iMac has installed? I downloaded Bluetooth Explorer and poked around, but I see no information that screams "Bluetooth version" at me. Nor could I find any data online mapping model numbers to Bluetooth versions.

I ask because I'm trying to do some work w/ 4.0 LE profiles. My Mac is an "iMac11,2".

Comment: If you have xcode installed, then you can hold down the option key and click on the bluetooth icon in the status bar and get a bunch of extra bluetooth options/info.

Comment: Cool tip! but I'm still not sure how to determine what this extra info means...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

System Profiler (apple > about this mac > more info > system report > hardware > bluetooth ) will tell you your "LMP version"

lookup that LMP version here http://www.bluetooth.org/Technical/AssignedNumbers/link_manager.htm

The key ones are:

LMP Version -> BT version

4 -> Bluetooth Core Specification 2.1 + EDR

6 -> Bluetooth Core Specification 4.0

Comment: Great answer, except it told me I don't have the bluetooth version I need. :(

Comment: 7 --> Bluetooth 4.1, 8 --> Bluetooth 4.2

Answer (score 2):

```
1.  Click the  menu.
2.  Select About This Mac.
3.  Click on the More Info... button.
4.  Click on the System Report... button.
5.  Select Bluetooth from the sidebar on the left, underneath "Hardware."
6.  Scan down the list of information until you find "LMP Version."
```

If your Mac is equipped with Bluetooth 4.0, LMP Version will say 0x6. Anything lower than that is an older version of Bluetooth

Source:
http://www.imore.com/how-tell-if-your-mac-has-bluetooth-40

Answer (score 1):

Found info on the hardware [here](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/specs/imac-core-i3-3.2-21-inch-aluminum-mid-2010-specs.html) by googling on "iMac11,2 specs". Looks like it is Bluetooth 2.1+EDR after all. (Makes sense, as it's a mid-2010 model.)

Still can't tell if there's a way to divine this in Bluetooth Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

The one liner listed in another answer doesn't work for me because my LMP version is reported as a hex number instead of a decimal number (0x6 instead of just 6).  It can be modified, though, to work whether it's decimal or hex by replacing the space before the number 6 with ".*".  Here is the modified one-liner that should work for all cases:

```
system_profiler -detailLevel full SPBluetoothDataType | grep -q "LMP Version:.*6" && echo "Your Mac is supported" || echo "Your Mac is not supported"
```

Answer (score 0):

One liner:

```
system_profiler -detailLevel full SPBluetoothDataType | grep -q "LMP Version: 6" && echo "Your Mac is supported" || echo "Your Mac is not supported"
```

Comment: On my system this one liner doesn't work properly because the line system_profiler returns is `LMP Version: 0x6`.